What is the physics behind if for conventional VOR, if the transmitting antenna rotated, amplitude modulation is produced?
Why for conventional VOR, the transmitting antenna is rotated? And how does it produce amplitude modulation? What is the physics behind this?

This question is similar to: What is the difference between conventional VOR and Doppler VOR?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how this answer on that question was not helpful for your problem.

Also the wording of this question sounds a bit homework-y, which is mostly OK but you have to put a bit more effort in if you want help.

The antenna could rotate, but usually it doesn't, only the field rotates. From the linked question: The cardioid EM field which constantly increases and decreases in strength at a given point in space as the pattern rotates is sensed by the receiver as a constant signal modulated in amplitude at 30 Hz, this amplitude variation represents the variable signal. The phase shift between this signal and the reference allows to determine the bearing.

@mins sorry I don't understand. I read your entire answer but still didn't understand. Can you direct me to the basic physics behind this?

@mins how amplitude modulation is produced with phased array?

@mins what is the physics behind this? Any keyword you can offer me?

Answering in chat.
